# Unclear ANSI CUB/CUF behaviour

Tags: c++, escaping, ansi-escape

While studying the ANSI control sequences I came across unclear behaviour.

I tried to make "matrix" effect in terminal, which
changes one random digit per loop iteration in a row of *n* 0/1 digits:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

const int n = 5; // row length
const int pause = 50; // milliseconds

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    using this_thread::sleep_for;
    using chrono::milliseconds;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      cout << rand() % 2;
    }

    int offset;
    while (true) {
      offset = rand() % n + 1; // random digit in row 1..n

      cout << "\x1b[" << offset << "D";
      cout.flush();
      sleep_for(milliseconds(pause));

      cout << rand() % 2;
      cout.flush();
      // cout << "\x1b[" << 1 << "D";
      // cout.flush();
      sleep_for(milliseconds(pause));

      cout << "\x1b[" << offset - 1 << "C";
      cout.flush();
      sleep_for(milliseconds(pause));
    }
}
```

As far as I understand **CSI offset D** moves cursor back *offset* times if it's possible in current row, then I `cout` random digit, that moves cursor 1 time forward, then I use **CSI offset - 1 C** to move it forward *offset - 1* times, that should return cursor to *n + 1* row position, so *n* digits go before cursor, but sometimes it goes further than *n + 1*, so, after several iterations it ends up at the end of the row. I would like to know why it happens.

However, when I use `cout << "\x1b[" << 1 << "D";` and then `cout << "\x1b[" << offset << "C";` instead of `cout << "\x1b[" << offset - 1 << "C";` it works fine.

I'm also aware of using **CSI n G**, which also works fine, but I want to understand what's going on with **CSI n C/D** . Maybe it's my maths fault, but not using `cout << "\x1b[" << 1 << "D";` seems to be equivalent of using `cout << "\x1b[" << offset - 1 << "C";` so it's really confusing to me.

Comment: Why are you moving cursor first backward then forward? And why `offset - 1` - once you write a digit, you have to move back one more, so it's `offset + 1`. Och - you want the cursor to "stay" on the right?

Comment: After `for` loop there are already n digits in the row (e.g if n = 5, then cursor position is 6), so I have to go back `offset` times (let's say 3, so cursor is at 6 - 3 = 3 position), then `cout` moves it 1 time forward (3 + 1 = 4), then I have move it `offset - 1` forward (4 + (3 - 1) = 6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `\x1b[0C` moves cursor to the right, at least on my terminal, (dunno if that is specified/required behavior).

```
$ printf "a\x1b[0Cb\n"
a b
$ printf "a\x1b[1Cb\n"
a b
```

Check if `offset - 1` is not zero.

```
if (offset - 1) {
  cout << "\x1b[" << offset - 1 << "C";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really does move it 1 time if I do it using 0 as `offset` value (for **CSI n D** the works the same). As I understand, it happens, when `offset` is 1, so `offset - 1` is 0 so **CUF** moves it anyway